# Reading data from my_Data class in my MainActivity using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

How to get 2 `array list` (1 `String` ,1 `Integer`) from `asynctask` and print them in `Mainactivity`??

### This my AsyncTask:

```
private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            Log.i("JSON", "Number of surveys in feed: " +jsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), jsonObject.getString("city"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               x.setStation_name(jsonObject.getString("city"));
               x.setStation_petrol_amount(jsonObject.getInt("amount"));

            }

            System.out.println("*******"+x.getStation_name());
            System.out.println("*******"+x.getStation_petrol_amount());



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
        }
```

Here my output in `system.out.print` >> and it's OK.

## This is my_Data class:

```
 public      ArrayList<String> city = new ArrayList<>() ;
      public      ArrayList<Integer> amount = new ArrayList<>() ;


    public  void setStation_petrol_amount(int station_petrol_amount) {
        amount.add(station_petrol_amount);
    }

    public  void setStation_name(String station_name)
    {
        city.add(station_name);
    }

       public  ArrayList<String> getStation_name()
    {
        return city;
    }

  public  ArrayList<Integer> getStation_petrol_amount() {
        return amount;
    }
```

### My mainActivity:

```
    new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute();
    ReadJSONFeedTask ob = new ReadJSONFeedTask();
        ob.execute("http://192.168.12.1/server/index.php");
        System.out.println(">>>>:"+x.getStation_name());
        System.out.println(">>>>:"+x.getStation_petrol_amount());
```

**The output if `system.out.print` >> has no data, how to get it??**

Comment: It would be nice if you rephrase your question. What would you like to achieve? You can keep both integer and string in the same arraylist of type my_Data.

Comment: but i need the two arraylist in my work

Comment: just i need get data from my_Data but when code run my_Data class still no have data in this time

Comment: It is due to its execution in Background, and have you considering using SparseArray which might suites batter for <Integer,String> type.

Comment: please iam not good enough in android can someone solve my problem by writing the code that i need or explan by example what i should do

Answer (score 0):

[How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

see the answer for the question.. you can pass your 2 array lists as parameter of the callback method to called activity once the thread finishes the work

in that example the interface should be modified like this

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
void processFinish(List<String> firstlist,List<Integer> secondlist);}
```

then in post execute you have to pass the result arraylist as parameters

OR you can pass the x objects list to called activity by replacing the interface like below

```
   public interface AsyncResponse {
void processFinish(List<X> firstlist);}
```

Comment: can u give me example of this way ?